# Android Application Force Closes when connecting to MySQL server?

Tags: android, json, xmlhttprequest

I have a very simple android application and have exported it to my android phone now it runs perfectly on start-up but when I click one of the two buttons that would connect to the MySQL server on my laptop via WiFi and using HTTPPOST and JSON (I have WAMP server up and running and have also edited ALL the users on my MySQL server to have all the permissions), it FORCE CLOSES.

Any ideas why?

I have set the URLs for accessing the php files to "http://localhost/exampleSite/example.php". Also if you are going to ask me about my Windows Firewall, I tried running the application with the Firewall disabled as I can't seem to see any options to allow "Port" connections.

I followed this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

every piece of coed there is the same as mine EXCEPT the URLs used for HTTPPOST/HTTPREQUEST

Comment: Am I overlooking anything here?

Comment: You need to use your computers IP address to connect to MySql, actually your phone can't access your Laptop this way, because your server is on computer and you are accessing it through the phone.

Comment: I tried that too.. I took a look for my IP at whatsmyip.org and used the value there but my android application still can't reach the server

Comment: What OS are you using? If you are using windows, use IPCONFIG @ command prompt.

Comment: how do I show my logcat?

Comment: I tried using the IPv4 Address that command prompt showed me using ipconfig it still force closes

Comment: Have you given internet permission in manifest file?

Comment: Yes I have, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: Logcat if you are using Eclipse, -> Window -> show view -> Logcat

Comment: post your code and relevant stuffs.

Comment: connect your phone through USB, did you?

Comment: I have it connected and charging to my laptop, why? It has its wifi on

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on emulator, try to access your WAMP server (which is the localhost) using IP address 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1

So your URL is going to look like

10.0.2.2/yourphpscript.php

---

According to your comment, you are testing on your actual device over USB.
Instead of connecting it using localhost

URL should be
192.168.0.75:8080/exampleSite/example.php
(192.168.0.75 is just an example)

Test if your current network environment allows your phone to establish HTTP connection with your laptop by entering your laptop's IP address and WAMP port number on your phone's web browser. 
-- So in android webbrowser URL bar, type in i.e. 192.168.0.5:8080

If this take you to your WAMP server directory, then you have no problem with your server setup

Comment: I am actually running my application on my android phone because I don't know how to run the android projects on an emulator. I'll try this

Comment: I tried it and it returns Network Problem. So this means I have a problem with my network configuration settings? how would I get around it?

Comment: it's best & efficient to make sure your connection to the WAMP server directory through android webbrowser by entering in URL something like your-laptop-ipaddress:port (e.g. 192.168.0.4:8080).

Comment: It is best to first test if you can even connect to your WAMP server on laptop by itself. If you can connect to your WAMP server on your laptop by itself, then problem should be with your firewall or router setting

Comment: I can connect to WAMP on my laptop. I couldn't connect to WAMP server on my android web browser

Comment: Should I edit the URLs for HttpRequests like "http://ipaddress:port/website/phpscript.php"?

Comment: "Should I edit the URLs for HttpRequests like "ipaddress:port/website/phpscript.php";?" To make it simple, yes.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of settings you have on your router. I recommend you to change the WAMP server's default port number to 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS) and allow those port connections in firewall settings then attempt to connect through android browser again

Comment: I can't seem to see that option in friewall settings. The "Add Port". So i just disabled my firewall altogether. I am using Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Enable them again, they are fine for now (but make sure you have added port 80). However, make sure your default WAMP server port is set to 80 (they are the ports to connect to web sites on your browser so they are most like to have no restrictions from router) as I have recommended. To do this, watch a tutorial video that tells you how to. Like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2mngQDZCRQ

Answer (score 0):

Change the url with your computers Ip address and connect your mobile phone through your computers internet.

```
http://localhost/exampleSite/example.php"
Ip address instead of localhost
```

Comment: I did and it still wouldn't connect